# Python AttributeError Object

Tags: python, attributes

What am I doing wrong? This is my homework assignment I am trying to finish. I got the weird syntax error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Ranbir\Desktop\myList2.py", line 56, in add
    myList.prev = myList.cursor
AttributeError: 'MyList' object has no attribute 'prev'
```

I don't see what I am doing wrong, the code looks perfect to me. The prev is defined in the ListNode and as well as mkListNode.

```
class EmptyListNode():
    """
    An empty list is an instance of EmptyListNode.
    """
    __slots__ = ()

class ListNode():
    """
    All true value-containing wheel nodes are represented as
    instances of ListNode.
    """
    __slots__ = ('data', 'next', 'prev')

class MyList():
    """
    The container for a linked wheel class.
    It contains a reference to a cursor in the wheel.
    Invariant: size==0 iff type(cursor)==EmptyListNode
    """
    __slots__ = ('cursor', 'size')

def mkList():
    """
    Makes a new list, with size 0, pointing to a Empty Node
    """
    mylist = MyList()
    mylist.cursor = EmptyListNode
    mylist.size = 0
    return mylist

def mkListNode(data, next, prev):
    """
    Make a new list node
    Returns a new node
    """
    listNode = ListNode()
    listNode.data = data
    listNode.next = next
    listNode.prev = prev
    return ListNode

def add(myList, element):
    """
    add: Add a node to the wheel right after the cursor
    Effect: A new node is in the wheel just after the cursor
    """
    myList.size += 1
    if myList.cursor == EmptyListNode:
        myList.cursor = mkListNode(EmptyListNode, element, EmptyListNode)
        myList.cursor.prev = myList.cursor
        myList.cursor.next = myList.cursor
    else:
        temp = mkListNode(myList.cursor.prev, element, myList.cursor.next)
        myList.cursor.prev.next = temp
        myList.cursor.prev = temp

def backward(List):
    """
    advance: Advance the cursor
    Effect: The cursor is now at the next node in the wheel
    """
    myList.cursor = List.cursor.prev

def forward(myList):
    """
    advance: Advance the cursor
    Effect: The cursor is now at the next node in the wheel
    """
    myList.cursor = myList.cursor.next

def getNext(List):
    """
    getNextElement: Get element at node after cursor position
    Effect: The element after cursor position is returned
    """
    return List.cursor.next.data

def getPrev(List):
    """
    getNextElement: Get element at node after cursor position
    Effect: The element after cursor position is returned
    """
    return List.cursor.prev.data

def printList(myList):
    """
    Prints the all the items in the wheel
    """
    string1 = ""
    current = myList.cursor
    for i in range(mylist.size):
        string1 += current.data
        current = current.next

def size(myList):
    """
    size: wheel -> numl
    """
    return mylist.size

def remove(myList):
    """
    remove: Remove the node at the cursor from the wheel
    Effect: The node after the wheel is removed
    Precondition: wheel size > 0
    """
    if size(myList) == 1:
        myList.cursor = EmptyListNode()
    else:
        myList.cursor.next.prev= List.cursor.prev
        myList.cursor.prev.next = List.cursor.next
        myList.cursor.data = List.cursor.prev.data
        myList.cursor = List.cursor.prev
        myList.cursor.prev.next = List.cursor
    myList.size -= 1
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myList.prev = myList.cursor
```

`myList` is apparently of type `MyList`, which does not define `prev` as a slot. Perhaps you meant this instead?

```
myList.cursor.prev = myList.cursor
myList.cursor.next = myList.cursor
```

Comment: Thanks alot! However I got another error. `listNode.next = next` which is under mkListNode. I got this error: `'ListNode' object attribute 'next' is read-only.