# Python AttributeError Object Attribute is read-only

Tags: python, attributes

```
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\myList2.py", line 44, in mkListNode
    listNode.next = next
AttributeError: 'ListNode' object attribute 'next' is read-only
```

I have no idea what is that means. Below is my whole code for the myList.py, any help would be great! Thanks

```
class ListNode():
    """
    All true value-containing wheel nodes are represented as
    instances of ListNode.
    """
    __slots__ = ('data', 'next', 'prev')

class MyList():
    """
    The container for a linked wheel class.
    It contains a reference to a cursor in the wheel.
    Invariant: size==0 iff type(cursor)==EmptyListNode
    """
    __slots__ = ('cursor', 'size')

def mkListNode(data, next, prev):
    """
    Make a new list node
    Returns a new node
    """
    listNode = ListNode()
    listNode.data = data
    listNode.next = next
    listNode.prev = prev
    return ListNode

def add(myList, element):
    """
    add: Add a node to the wheel right after the cursor
    Effect: A new node is in the wheel just after the cursor
    """
    myList.size += 1
    if myList.cursor == EmptyListNode:
        myList.cursor = mkListNode(EmptyListNode, element, EmptyListNode)
        myList.cursor.prev = myList.cursor
        myList.cursor.next = myList.cursor
    else:
        temp = mkListNode(myList.cursor.prev, element, myList.cursor.next)
        myList.cursor.prev.next = temp
        myList.cursor.prev = temp
```

I don't see why the ListNode would be only a read-only? Hmm, that is interesting, never seed the read-only about the object attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python AttributeError Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946948/python-attributeerror-object)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers no. This time I got another error, which is the `read-only`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Copy-pasting your code and calling `mkListNode` I don't get any `AttributeError`. Please show how you are calling those functions.

Comment: Same here. I can't reproduce the code. Where are you running this?

Comment: @aIKid am running from ww.py file which is located: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948752/python-does-not-remove

Comment: @Bakuriu am running from ww.py file which is located: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948752/python-does-not-remove

Comment: which python version?

Comment: No idea. Works fine here, i can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not going to read those hundred of line to find this bug. The code is pretty bad (for example all the functions `getNext`, `getPrev` etc. should actually be methods of the classes. So your code is much more complicated then what it could be). If you provide a *minimal* working example I might check that.

Comment: @Bakuriu wouldn't be `def mkListNode(data, next, prev):` be `class mkListNode(data, next, prev):`?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: You probably don't want to return `ListNode` in `mkListNode`. `ListNode` is the class. `listNode` is the instance you just created. Also, are you sure you want to represent empty list nodes by a reference to the class `EmptyListNode`, rather than as `EmptyListNode` instances?

Answer (score 1):

next is a Python builtin word. Try changing next to another variable.

Comment: `next` is a builtin _function_, not a reserved word. You can rebind the name like with any other builtin (whether this is a good idea is another topic).